# how to write down the dual of the linear programming problem?

Tags: linear-programming

> Write down the dual of the linear programming problem:
>
> Max. : $2x + 3y$
>
> such that
>
> $x + 2y = 3$
>
> $2x + y ≥ 4$
>
> $x + y ≤ 5$
>
> $x ≥ 0 , y ≥ 0.$

My attempt : Min $ 3w_1 + 4w_2$ such that

$w_1 + 2w_3 +w_3 \ge 2$

$2w_1 +w_2 +w_3 \ge 3$

$w_1 \ge 0 , w_2 \ge 0$

Is its true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things are right, but there are some mistakes. Especially the variable $w_3$ must be at the objective function. I´ve used the table below to obtain the dual program.

$\texttt{min} \ \ 3w_1 + 4w_2+5w_3$ such that

$w_1 + 2w_3 +w_3 \ge 2$

$2w_1 +w_2 +w_3 \ge 3$

$w_2\leq 0, w_3\geq 0$

[image]